Ошибка при установке плагина database navigator
при попытке установить в PyCharm плагин Database Navigator, возникает ошибка:
Plugin "Database Navigator" was not installed: Request failed with status code 451
Кто знает как решить данную проблему?


Это ошибка возникает при попытке установить что угодно и у меня она возникла где-то месяца два назад точно.

451 код состояния означает, что скачивание недоступно по политическим причинам для вашего региона (подробнее).
А сам JetBrains ограничил возможность загрузки как своих продуктов, так и некоторых плагинов для пользователей РФ с лета 2024 года. Вот, например, обсуждение этого вопроса в разделе поддержки JetBrains. Если всё-таки требуется установка, то воспользуйтесь VPN.
